# HTTP Problems with Google Fonts

Tags: magento-1.9, https, google-analytics, http-request

I need to change all of the "http://" to "https://" in a file on my site. I did these steps. By the way, I'm using Magento 1.9.2.4 and a Chromebook -

1. I right clicked on my site and clicked "Inspect".
2. The screen splits in two, and on the right there is a message saying:

'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700|Open+Sans:400,700,600italic,300|Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

3. I click on this and get taken to this link:

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700|Open+Sans:400,700,600italic,300|Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700

4. I right click on "view page source" and then I right click again and click "Inspect".
5. The screen splits in two and on the right at the top there are tabs that say "Elements, Console, Sources, Network, Timeline, and Profiles".
6. I clicked on "Elements", double clicked on the code I wanted to edit (you can also right click and hit "Edit Text" or "Edit as HTML"), and typed an "s" in front of all the links that say "http://" and change them to "https://".
7. However, there is no way to save this file where the next time I go to my site, it won't have these problems.
8. I tried going to the "Sources" tab and add an "s" in front of the "http://", but I can't edit this file in the "Sources" section directly.

How can I change all of the "http://" links to say "https://"?

Please give as DETAILED information as possible
Ex - Go to CPanel, click on..., scroll to the middle of ... file, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to understand editing from browser console is only for testing purpose. It will not save it in to your server. Just imagine if it would save from there, then anyone would destroy your site.

**What is the error?**

> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

This means you are trying to load non secure links (http://) in to your secured site (https://). You have to make sure all your content runs with `https://`

**Now, how to change this in your server?**

For this you will need to have ftp access. Simply login to ftp and find the file that corresponds to this google font.

I think it should be in your one of css file.

All css files are located in this:

```
skin/frontend/[theme_package]/[your_theme]/css/file.css
```

[*You can find exact file location from browser console (inspect element)*](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-use-Chromes-Inspect-Element-to-locate-the-file-I-would-need-to-edit-to-save-changes-locally)

Now, you can edit this file and replace this:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700|Open+Sans:400,700,600italic,300|Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700
```

with this:

```
//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700|Open+Sans:400,700,600italic,300|Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700
```

This will make sure it will load with `http://` and `https://` both.

Comment: Thanks! What will happen if it loads with both http:// and https://?

Comment: It will trigger no error for you, which is normal behavior we intend to achieve.

Comment: Ok thanks! What happens if I add an "s" in front of "http://"?

Comment: That will help too, but remember, in future if your site don't run with https:// then again you will have to change these. So simply make it run through both case scenario would be wise.

Comment: Thanks again! There isn't a file named "file.css". Did you mean a certain name instead of "file"?

Comment: Yes, it is your own file.

Comment: There are some different .css files. I will list all of them -

Comment: animate.css, bootstrap-theme.css, bootstrap-theme.css.map, bootstrap.css, bootstrap.css.map, jquery.fancybox.css, main-bkp.css, nivo-slider.css, print.css, reset.css, sequencejs-theme.modern-slide-in.css, styles-ie.css, styles.css.

Comment: Do you have live url? if you don't have please add a screenshot where I can see those red error line. Finding error file is not hard. If you just right click on error line and click on "open in new tab" you will see the exact file path in url.

Comment: Which .css file do I go into to edit the "http://" links? Also, is there a way to automatically set all of these "http://" links to "https://", or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700|Open+Sans:400,700,600italic,300|Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700

Comment: How can I directly edit this file and save it on my server?

Comment: You have to find the file, then edit the file and make the changes there. I cannot say which file it is? `Finding error file is not hard. If you just right click on error line and click on "open in new tab" you will see the exact file path in url.` This is simple task, if you still don't know how to do it, add your screenshot where error lines  are visible.

Comment: I did that and changed all the "http://" links to "https://" in "Elements" and I saved the file to my computer. But, I don't know how to save it to my server.

Comment: How do I save the new "https://" version to my server?